# Reading file in python

Tags: python, weather

ok so i have a command in python to write to a file

```
 from urllib.request import urlretrieve
urlretrieve('http://www.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=29bsTnYaZT&output=json&query=50323&temp_unit=f','weatherfile.txt')
```

and then a coommand to open that file

```
with open ('/home/pi/weatherfile.txt','r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

this is the out put i get

```
{ "weather": { "curren_weather": [ {"humidity": "62", "pressure": "1007", "temp": "86", "temp_unit": "f", "weather_code": "1", "weather_text": "Partly cloudy",  "wind": [ {"dir": "S", "speed": "6", "wind_unit": "kph" } ] } ],  "forecast": [ {"date": "2013-06-26",  "day": [ {"weather_code": "0", "weather_text": "Sunny skies",  "wind": [ {"dir": "W", "dir_degree": "266", "speed": "11", "wind_unit": "kph" } ] } ], "day_max_temp": "93",  "night": [ {"weather_code": "0", "weather_text": "Clear skies",  "wind": [ {"dir": "NW", "dir_degree": "313", "speed": "22", "wind_unit": "kph" } ] } ], "night_min_temp": "68", "temp_unit": "f" }, {"date": "2013-06-27",  "day": [ {"weather_code": "1", "weather_text": "Partly cloudy skies",  "wind": [ {"dir": "NNE", "dir_degree": "27", "speed": "18", "wind_unit": "kph" } ] } ], "day_max_temp": "86",  "night": [ {"weather_code": "29", "weather_text": "Thundery outbreaks possible",  "wind": [ {"dir": "NNE", "dir_degree": "20", "speed": "18", "wind_unit": "kph" } ] } ], "night_min_temp": "65", "temp_unit": "f" } ] }}
```

i want it to output it a little nicer is there a way i can do that?

heres an update of the ones ive tried

```
froom urllib.request import urlretrieve
urlretrieve('http://api.wunderground.com/api/015098ae0bc15cce/conditions/q/IA/Urbandale.json','weatherfile.txt')
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
with open ('/home/pi/weatherfile.txt','r') as f:
    d = json.loads(f.read())
    pp.pprint(d)
```

and i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Grant/Desktop/getweather.py", line 3, in <module>
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
NameError: name 'pprint' is not defined
```

Comment: to pretty print json file, you could run on the command line: `python -mjson.tool weatherfile.txt`

Answer (score 2):

I assume it is JSON data, so you can pretty print it using [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.htm):

```
import json
with open ('/home/pi/weatherfile.txt','r') as f:
    d = json.loads(f.read())
    json.dumps(sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

or you can do it using [pprint](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html):

```
import json
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
with open ('/home/pi/weatherfile.txt','r') as f:
    d = json.loads(f.read())
    pp.pprint(d)
```

Comment: i get incunsetent use of tabs and spaces

Comment: normally, when you insert the `indent=4` parametee, you should get only spaces

Comment: now getting trackback error jason is not defined for the first one and for the second suggestion i get pprint is not defiend

Comment: oh you did not import the module :-) prepend `import pprint` (updating my answer)

Comment: getting an error now (unicode error)'unicodeescape" codec cant decode bytes in position 2-3:truncated\UXXXxXXXX escape

Comment: when i open this file on my pi i get error json is not defined

Comment: did you also `import json`? The error `XXX is not defined` where XXX is likely to be a module (like `json`, `pprint`, `sys`, `os`...) means that you need to `import XXX`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> Data
{'weather': {'curren_weather': [{'temp_unit': 'f', 'temp': '86', 'weather_code': '1', 'humidity': '62', 'pressure': '1007', 'weather_text': 'Partly cloudy', 'wind': [{'wind_unit': 'kph', 'speed': '6', 'dir': 'S'}]}], 'forecast': [{'temp_unit': 'f', 'day_max_temp': '93', 'night_min_temp': '68', 'night': [{'weather_text': 'Clear skies', 'weather_code': '0', 'wind': [{'dir_degree': '313', 'speed': '22', 'wind_unit': 'kph', 'dir': 'NW'}]}], 'date': '2013-06-26', 'day': [{'weather_text': 'Sunny skies', 'weather_code': '0', 'wind': [{'dir_degree': '266', 'speed': '11', 'wind_unit': 'kph', 'dir': 'W'}]}]}, {'temp_unit': 'f', 'day_max_temp': '86', 'night_min_temp': '65', 'night': [{'weather_text': 'Thundery outbreaks possible', 'weather_code': '29', 'wind': [{'dir_degree': '20', 'speed': '18', 'wind_unit': 'kph', 'dir': 'NNE'}]}], 'date': '2013-06-27', 'day': [{'weather_text': 'Partly cloudy skies', 'weather_code': '1', 'wind': [{'dir_degree': '27', 'speed': '18', 'wind_unit': 'kph', 'dir': 'NNE'}]}]}]}}
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps (Data,  sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
{
    "weather": {
        "curren_weather": [
            {
                "humidity": "62",
                "pressure": "1007",
                "temp": "86",
                "temp_unit": "f",
                "weather_code": "1",
                "weather_text": "Partly cloudy",
                "wind": [
                    {
                        "dir": "S",
                        "speed": "6",
                        "wind_unit": "kph"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "forecast": [
            {
                "date": "2013-06-26",
                "day": [
                    {
                        "weather_code": "0",
                        "weather_text": "Sunny skies",
                        "wind": [
                            {
                                "dir": "W",
                                "dir_degree": "266",
                                "speed": "11",
                                "wind_unit": "kph"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "day_max_temp": "93",
                "night": [
                    {
                        "weather_code": "0",
                        "weather_text": "Clear skies",
                        "wind": [
                            {
                                "dir": "NW",
                                "dir_degree": "313",
                                "speed": "22",
                                "wind_unit": "kph"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "night_min_temp": "68",
                "temp_unit": "f"
            },
            {
                "date": "2013-06-27",
                "day": [
                    {
                        "weather_code": "1",
                        "weather_text": "Partly cloudy skies",
                        "wind": [
                            {
                                "dir": "NNE",
                                "dir_degree": "27",
                                "speed": "18",
                                "wind_unit": "kph"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "day_max_temp": "86",
                "night": [
                    {
                        "weather_code": "29",
                        "weather_text": "Thundery outbreaks possible",
                        "wind": [
                            {
                                "dir": "NNE",
                                "dir_degree": "20",
                                "speed": "18",
                                "wind_unit": "kph"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "night_min_temp": "65",
                "temp_unit": "f"
            }
        ]
    }
}
>>>
```

The type of Data what you got is called JSON encoded. Solution taken from http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html.

Comment: incsestent use of indent and spaces

Comment: Can you please edit and update the question with the current program which produces that error?

Comment: for yours i've tried a bunch of diffrent ways to try with info youve provided and they all fail with some sort of error invaild synthax unexceptect indent

Comment: Can you please edit and update the question with the current program which produces that error?